# spring data jpa utf-8 encoding not working

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use `spring-data-jpa` and `mysql` database. My tables character set is utf-8. Also I added `?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8` to mysql url in application.properties file. Problem when I pass characters like "ąčęėį" to controller to save it in mysql. In mysql I got ??? marks. But when I use mysql console example `update projects_data set data="ąęąčę" where id = 1;` every works well.

application.properties:

```
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gehive?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username = gehive
spring.datasource.password = pass

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy


# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

tables:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
| TABLE_NAME    | character_set_name |
+---------------+--------------------+           
| customer      | utf8               |
| projects      | utf8               |
| projects_data | utf8               |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gehive?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

It seems issue is due to missing "-".

Reference:-
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1037497&view=next

Comment: `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` is not working for me.Can you please give me a solution to this?

Comment: For spring mvc, `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issues, and I solved it by adding this line to my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

*Note:* The following *didn't* work:

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

Comment: I had done the configurations which are mentioned about mysql config file or application.properties. But, it works when I add that line. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using the HikariCP connection pool who prefers not to append the parameters directly to the JDBC URL:

The `spring.datasource.connectionProperties` property was removed some time ago. Since then, you need to use connection pool specific properties as shown in @SebTheGreat's answer:
`spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;`

Hikari doesn't have a `connection-properties` property, but this works:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: A lifesaver. These seem to be necessary when you add Hikari's connection pool properties on Spring Boot. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me: ```spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;```

Comment: Worked for me - when using external tomcat with spring boot and Hikari Connection Pool!

Answer (score 2):

Remember to escape any special characters, as below:
    `spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/${SERVER_DB_NAME}\?useUnicode=true\&characterEncoding=utf\-8\&characterSetResults=utf\-8`

Comment: it just gives error, as expected. it incorrect, and just breaks application configuration

Comment: SERVER_DB_NAME is an environment variable, just in case if you are unclear about it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case that's solve my issue 
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution depending your configuration is using [@SqlConfig annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlConfig.html)

```
@Sql(config = @SqlConfig(encoding = "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if using mysql java connector version 5.1.44 (before I used connector 8.0.17 it doesn't work)