# Does the JDBC Postgres Driver has a way to set the "client_encoding" to connect to the database?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, character-encoding

Does the JDBC Postgres Driver has a way to set the `client_encoding` to connect to the database?

I am using Spring (with JPA) and the connection information is in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://mypgserver.com:5432/mydb?user=myuser&password=mypass&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

But reading the JDBC docs at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html, I didn't find a parameter named `characterEncoding`.

In fact, there is no parameter for this purpose in the docs.

How can I set the encoding to be used when inputting data to the PG server?

Comment: you are reading the wrong doc ! you talk about `spring.datasource.url` which is a spring property, you should look at spring doc not pg doc. Have you look at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677740/spring-data-jpa-utf-8-encoding-not-working)

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi the property contains a JDBC connection. Are you sure I'm reading the wrong doc? Can you send me a link to the right one?

Comment: The interpretation of a JDBC url is done by the driver, so I think you are reading the correct doc.

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi That question is about MySQL, not PostgreSQL. Connection properties are driver specific (except the two properties `user` and `password` defined in the JDBC API), so the OP was looking at the correct documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Java uses a UNICODE encoding (UTF-16) internally, it would be unnatural to use a `client_encoding` different from `UTF8` in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Consequently, it forces `client_encoding` to that values, see [`org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.getParametersForStartup`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/57ca33353bb1e05135063a79069c1c320662ae1c/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java#L334):

```java
private List<String[]> getParametersForStartup(String user, String database, Properties info) {
  List<String[]> paramList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  paramList.add(new String[]{"user", user});
  paramList.add(new String[]{"database", database});
  paramList.add(new String[]{"client_encoding", "UTF8"});
  paramList.add(new String[]{"DateStyle", "ISO"});
  [...]
```

In fact, if the client encoding is changed to anything else, [the JDBC driver expresses its unhappiness](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/57ca33353bb1e05135063a79069c1c320662ae1c/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L2690) in no uncertain terms:

```java
public void receiveParameterStatus() throws IOException, SQLException {
  // ParameterStatus
  pgStream.receiveInteger4(); // MESSAGE SIZE
  String name = pgStream.receiveString();
  String value = pgStream.receiveString();

  [...]

  if (name.equals("client_encoding")) {
    if (allowEncodingChanges) {
      if (!value.equalsIgnoreCase("UTF8") && !value.equalsIgnoreCase("UTF-8")) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE,
            "pgjdbc expects client_encoding to be UTF8 for proper operation. Actual encoding is {0}",
            value);
      }
      pgStream.setEncoding(Encoding.getDatabaseEncoding(value));
    } else if (!value.equalsIgnoreCase("UTF8") && !value.equalsIgnoreCase("UTF-8")) {
      close(); // we're screwed now; we can't trust any subsequent string.
      throw new PSQLException(GT.tr(
          "The server''s client_encoding parameter was changed to {0}. The JDBC driver requires client_encoding to be UTF8 for correct operation.",
          value), PSQLState.CONNECTION_FAILURE);

    }
  }
```

You probably have an encoding conversion problem when you read the data into your Java program; try and fix the problem there.

Comment: Java used to use `UCS-2` in the beginning. From 5.0, Java uses `UTF-16` as the internal encoding.

Comment: Thank you and please find the reference: `The native character encoding of the Java programming language is UTF-16. A charset in the Java platform therefore defines a mapping between sequences of sixteen-bit UTF-16 code units (that is, sequences of chars) and sequences of bytes.`[Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Comment: Thanks again for the good faith. Your current answer is perfectly good :-)